# Unable to add row to SQLite database using Flask and Flask-WTF

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-wtforms

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while. I am trying to add a row to my SQLite database that contains data from a submitted form. However, no data seems to be getting added to my database. What's odd is when I run the function (detailed below) that adds data to the database manually, things work fine. :/ Any help would be much appreciated!

I have four code sections below, the creation of the Signup Form, the flask routing function, the database insertion method, and finally the HTML for the form.

I create my SignupForm using Flask-WTF as follows,

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length

class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired("Username required!")])
    first_name = StringField("First Name", validators=[DataRequired("First name required!")])
    last_name = StringField("Last Name", validators=[DataRequired("Last name required!")])
    email = StringField("E-Mail", validators=[DataRequired("E-mail required!"), Email("Please enter a valid e-mail!")])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired("Password required!"), Length(min=5, message=("Password must be at least 5 characters."))])
    submit = SubmitField("Sign up!")
```

Following that, is my signup() function in my routing file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, flash
from forms import SignupForm 
import database_methods

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "development key"

@app.route('/signup', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    """ Signs a user up for an account so that they may log in """
    form = SignupForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not form.validate(): # ensure that a user enters all fields correctly
            return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
        else:
            username = form.username.data
            first_name = form.first_name.data
            last_name = form.last_name.data
            email = form.email.data
            password = form.password.data
            database_methods.insert_row_in_db(username, first_name, last_name, email, password)

            return "All right! Signed up!"

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

Finally, we have the actual method to insert the data a user inputted into the form.

```
import sqlite3
import os
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from uuid import uuid4

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DB_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "chat.sqlite")


def insert_row_in_db(username, firstname, lastname, email, password):
    """ Creates a row in chat.sqlite's users table """
    uid = uuid4().hex
    pwd_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
    login_time = set_lastlogin(uid)
    row_data = (uid, username, firstname, lastname, email, pwd_hash, login_time, True)

    with sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH) as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO users (uid, username, firstname, lastname, email, passwordhash, 
                  lastlogin, loggedin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);''', row_data)
```

If the HTML file is needed for reference, here it is.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<main>
    <div>
         <h2>Create an Account</h2>

         <form method="POST" action="/signup">
             {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

             <div>
                {{ form.username.label }}

                {% if form.username.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                        <p> {{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {{ form.username }}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{ form.first_name.label }}

                {% if form.first_name.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
                        <p> {{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {{ form.first_name }}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{ form.last_name.label }}

                {% if form.last_name.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.last_name.errors %}
                        <p> {{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {{ form.last_name }}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{ form.email.label }}

                {% if form.email.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                        <p> {{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {{ form.email }}
            </div>

            <div>
                {{ form.password.label }}

                {% if form.password.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <p> {{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {{ form.password }}
            </div>

            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
        </form>
    </div>
</main>

{% endblock content %}
```

I have been googling for a few hours now, and have tried many things to no avail. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!!

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Do you get any errors or does the insert_row_in_db ()  return successfully?

Comment: I get no errors. It is failing silently. When I run insert_row_in_db() manually, things work completely fine and the row gets added to the database.

Comment: Additionally, in signup(), if I simply return the formatted string of username, first_name, last_name, etc., those elements display perfectly fine on a web-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Docker and have never used it before. Turns out, docker was creating a separate database from the one I was using in PyCharm. My code was indeed working, it was just adding it to a different database than the one I Was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try call `commit` method after querying? In Flask documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/#initial-schemas, It commits after querying like this.

```py
def init_db():
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried to commit() and tried to clear() both are unsuccessful in inserting a line into the db. I assume it is because by default, the `with sqlite3.connect ... :` line commits and closes a connection if successful.

Comment: As far as initializing the database, I already have the database initialized (I am using PyCharm which made the initialization quite easy).